# How to slow down window.location.href on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to find a way to slow down the reload of page that `window.location.href` does.
This is needed because the animation of toggle button is not shown.
Is there a way?

Here code used:

```js
$(".closeMan").change(function () {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./close_man.php",
      success: function (result) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
      },
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: By "slow down" you mean "delay", right?

Comment: use `setTimeout(() => {  window.location.href = window.location.href; }, 2000);`

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad english. I meant "delay", NOT slow down :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `setTimeout` (if you really need to slow down your application...):

```
$(".closeMan").change(function () {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./close_man.php",
        success: () => {
          window.location.href = window.location.href;
        },
      });
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timeout, and [window.location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 1000); // Time in milliseconds
```

Note: you cant call it like `setTimeout(window.location.reload, 1000)` because you will get an `Illegal invocation` error.

Answer (score 0):

You may use settimeout to handle timing problem.

```
$(".closeMan").change(function () {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    setTimeout(function(){   
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./close_man.php",
        success: function (result) {
         window.location.href = window.location.href;
        },
       });
      }
     }, 1000);
});
```